# How to change SyncBlockIndex and object instance type to not compatible at runtime?

Tags: c#, clr

Need to change SyncBlockIndex and object's type at runtime. For example:

```
class A { ... }
class B { ... }

A a = new A();
B b = (?)a;
```

I know this is stupid, but I think this is possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After little investigation I have found how to change SyncBlockIndex and EEClass (which is actually object's type) runtime. To do this, please copy'n'paste following listing to newly created console application and run it on `32-bit` target (on `64-bit` target UInt32 should be changed to UInt64)

Pro tip: `GCHandle.Alloc().AddrOfPinnedObject()` and other `GCHandle` methods returns not object's address, but something else, like 'synonym'.

## Result:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    public static class ObjectGCEx
    {
        public static unsafe ObjContents *GetGCFields(this object obj)
        {
            return (ObjContents*)((new ObjPointer { Object = obj }).Pointer);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets private GC object's fields SyncBlockIndex and EEClass struct pointer
        /// </summary>
        public static unsafe void GetGCFields(this object obj, out UInt32 syncBlockIndex, out UInt32 eeClass)
        {
            var contents = (ObjContents*)((new ObjPointer { Object = obj }).Pointer);
            syncBlockIndex = contents->syncBlockIndex;
            eeClass = contents->eeClass;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets private GC object's fields SyncBlockIndex and EEClass struct pointer
        /// </summary>
        public static unsafe UInt32 GetSyncBlockIndex(this object obj)
        {
            var contents = (ObjContents*)((new ObjPointer { Object = obj }).Pointer);
            return contents->syncBlockIndex;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets private GC object's fields SyncBlockIndex and EEClass struct pointer
        /// </summary>
        public static unsafe UInt32 GetEEClass(this object obj)
        {
            var contents = (ObjContents*)((new ObjPointer { Object = obj }).Pointer);
            return contents->eeClass;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets private GC object's field SyncBlockIndex, which is actually index in private GC table.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">Object with SyncBlockIndex to be changed</param>
        /// <param name="syncBlockIndex">New value of SyncBlockIndex</param>
        public static unsafe void SetSyncBlockIndex(this object obj, UInt32 syncBlockIndex)
        {
            var contents = (ObjContents*)((new ObjPointer { Object = obj }).Pointer);
            contents->syncBlockIndex = syncBlockIndex;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets private GC object's field EEClass, which is actually describes current class pointer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">Object with SyncBlockIndex to be changed</param>
        /// <param name="syncBlockIndex">New value of SyncBlockIndex</param>
        public static unsafe void SetEEClass(this object obj, UInt32 eeClass)
        {
            var contents = (ObjContents*)((new ObjPointer { Object = obj }).Pointer);
            contents->eeClass = eeClass;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct ObjPointer
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal object Object;

        [FieldOffset(4)]
        internal uint _pointer;

        internal unsafe uint Pointer
        {
            get {
                fixed(uint *pp = &_pointer)
                {
                    return *(uint *)((uint)pp - sizeof(uint)) - sizeof(uint);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct ObjContents
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public UInt32 syncBlockIndex;

        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public UInt32 eeClass;

        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public byte fieldsStart;
    }

    public class MainClass      
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public int x = 123;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "From Person";
            }
        }

        public class Customer
        {
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "From Customer";
            }
        }

        public unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var first = new Person();
            var second = new Customer();

            unsafe
            {
                Console.WriteLine("type of first: {0}, ToString(): {1}", first.GetType().Name, first);

                first.SetEEClass(second.GetEEClass());

                Console.WriteLine("type of first: {0}, ToString(): {1}", first.GetType().Name, first);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
type of first: Person, ToString(): From Person
type of first: Customer, ToString(): From Customer
```

for same object. This code not protected from GC collections.

## Mono Related

Mono memory is different. It starts from object's start (not from -1 word like at .Net Framework) and SyncBlockIndex is at 2nd position, not at first. And SyncBlockInex is not index but pointer to sync structure.

## Published as library at GitHub

https://github.com/mumusan/dotnetex

Comment: ..after 10 seconds of investigation??

Comment: I have posted this to share knowledge :) Of course, this takes 1 day of investigation, not 10 seconds :)